# Prove $ f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ via $ \ f(a,b) = 12^{a}.18^{b}$ is injective and not surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Question:

Let $ f: \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}  \to \mathbb{N}$ via $ \ f(a,b) = 12^{a}.18^{b}$

(a) Prove that $\ f$ is injective.

(b) Is $ \ f$ surjective ?

My attempt:

Part a:

Suppose $ f(x,y) = f(c,d)$ for $ x,y,c,d \in \mathbb{N}$

Then $ 12^{x}.18^{y} = 12^{c}.18^{d}$

From here how can I show that $ (x,y) = (c,d)$?

Part b:

No. Since $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ the minimum value of  $a$ and $b$ is $1$. So $ 12^{a}.18^{b} \ge 12.18 = 216.$ So all the natural numbers from $1$ to $216$ are not in the image of the function.

Comment: Hint: start with $12^a \cdot 18^b = 2^{2a}\cdot 3^a \cdot 2^b \cdot 3^{2b}=2^{2a+b} \cdot 3^{a+2b}\,$.

Comment: Alternative solution for part b: every element of the image of $f$ is even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the unique prime fatorization theorem.

If $12^a18^b = 12^p13^q$, and without loss of generality $a \geq p$, then $12^{a-p} = 18^{q-b}$, which then gives $2^{2(a-p)}3^{(a-p)} = 2^{b-q}3^{2(b-q)}$.

Now, since both LHS and RHS are completely prime factorized, we have that the powers of primes on both sides should match. Hence, the power of two matches i.e. $2(a-p)  = b-q$, and the power of three matches i.e. $2(b-q) = a-p$.

Subtituting the second equation in the first, we get $4(a-p) = a-p$, so $a-p=0$ and then $b-q = 0$, so $a=p,b=q$ follows.

Part $b$ is correct, for the reason  you have given, namely that $1,2,...,215$ are not in the image of the function.

Comment: In part b, 1 is not included in the image as well right?

Comment: I have seen clashes in convention, where the natural numbers are indicated to  start from $0$ or $1$. Going by the convention that $1$ is the starting number, we can also say that $1$ is not included in the image. I will add it.